# Can i use Google Maps on my Windows 10 (UWP) Apps

Tags: google-maps, windows-10, win-universal-app

So, I was looking to create Universal Windows Platform app (targeting both mobile and desktop) that actually showing a maps with a marker that came from lat & long saved in a database. But I want to using Google Maps to show it.

How can I do this? I mean, is it possible?

Which GMaps API should I use? JavaScript API, or the Web Srvice API?

I've been thinking that maybe I could use the web view to achieve this, to show the maps. But is this the right way or any other way?

Glad if someone can help and give an opinion.
(and sorry for my bad grammar, if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not provide any SDKs for working with `Google Maps`.

Basically, proposed to use native [`MapControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.aspx). You can look [Source Code Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl).

But you can add `WebView` to display `Google Maps`. You can create your own `html` page with `JavaScript` functions. For invoke your `JavaScript` functions use `InvokeScriptAsync`. You can look the simple sample: [HOW TO COMMUNICATE WITH WEBVIEW JAVASCRIPT FROM C#](https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/winrt-how-to-communicate-with-javascript-from-c-and-vice-versa/)

Comment: GoogleMaps does have an Android SDK. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

Comment: @SChalice we talked about SDKs for UWP/Windows Phone development

Answer (score 1):

You can create a MapControl just as you would on a website.

Include their script at the top of your page:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then include a div to contain the map:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute"></div>
```

You can manipulate the map and add new items to it (markers, long / lat, etc) but referencing that id "map-canvas" from any additional JS file you create.

Comment: Security in Windows 10 apps will block the externally hosted script file from being loaded.

Comment: I thought you could wrap functions in MSExecuteUnsafe

Comment: At least that's what I've been doing for years, and it's worked: http://www.davevoyles.com/2013/09/23/hacking-jquery-to-work-in-windows-8/

Comment: That won't work as the actual map script would have been blocked from being loaded before you even get to a point where you would try and call any of it's functions.

Comment: This has always worked for me under many different implementations. You just need a GoogleMap's key.

Comment: I've done the exact same thing. *shrug* Other people just like to down vote folks. #StackOverflowToxic